# Filtering low quality posts by questions or answers under reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, filtering, low-quality-posts

I think the question is quite self explanatory. It'd be nice to be able to filter low quality posts by questions or answers, just like we allow reviewing both, first questions and first answers (instead of something like first posts).

Answer (score 1):

This feature now exists by clicking the Filter link next to the title:

[image: filter on Q or A or tag]

You can then select Questions, Answers and/or up to 3 tags to filter on.

After clicking Okay your filter is applied and saved.

You can construct an url that sets the tag selection directly. Use the filter-tags query parameter for that, as shown in this example to filter on [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon)

[`https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?filter-tags=amazon`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?filter-tags=amazon)